# How do I modify the query parameters?

Tags: 7, uri

I want to modify query parameters used when accessing a Drupal page. I tried implementing `hook_url_inbound_alter()`, but it only allows to parse/modify the path, and it doesn't allow any interaction with the query string.

I see there is also [`drupal_get_query_parameters()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_get_query_parameters/7.x), which allows to read the query parameters.

I *could* detect the presence of a query value in index.php and do a string replacement on the value if needed, but I don't want to pollute the front controller.

Do you have any better advice?

Comment: You would need to modify the global `$_GET` at some early stage, maybe `hook_boot`

Answer (score 4):

1) you need to implement EventSubscriber, use `KernelEvents::REQUEST` in getSubscribedEvents() method

2) then you use `\Drupal::request()->query->set('key', 'value');`

Comment: Thanks for your answer but is this for Drupal 8? I am using 7.

Comment: Add \Drupal::request()->overrideGlobals(); after modifying the query parameters in order to persist changes when further reading the query parameters